# Video not full size on the background of a section

Tags: html, css, video

I'm working on a site that has a video as a background of one of the sections. Similar to, https://templated.co/broadcast. The issue with the template I'm using is that there are large white areas around the video, almost like it isn't 100% wide, which is what they say here: [CSS - Background Video Seems To Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118028/css-background-video-seems-to-zoom?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), because I initially had the issue that the video was too zoomed in, but adding a padding bottom seems like a bit of a hack, surely there is a better way to solve this problem.

My html and css are as follows, so you can see what's happening.

```css
#videobcg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}

header {
  padding: 100px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.img-holder {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-gradient" id="home">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h1>Mobile App Landing Page Template</h1>
    <p class="tagline">The one and only solution for any kind of mobila app landing needs. Just change the screenshots and texts and you are good to go. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder mt-3"><img src="images/iphonex.png" alt="phone" class="img-fluid">
    <video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
      <source src="https://static.lumosity.com/resources/home_page_templates/574/neuralnetwork.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
     </video>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution. Just change your CSS like this:

```
#videobcg {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Now you are using max-width: 100%. try min-width it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `object-fit: cover`:

> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>   filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio
>   does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be
>   clipped to fit.

Whereas the `width` and `height` of `100%` (or *viewport units*) also need to be set for the same *element*:

```css
body {margin: 0} /* remove the default margin */

header {
  margin-top: 100px; /* modified */
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#videobcg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%; /* or 100vw */
  height: 100%; /* or 100vh */
  object-fit: cover; /* added */
}

.img-holder {
  height: 0;
  /*padding-bottom: 33%;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-gradient" id="home">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h1>Mobile App Landing Page Template</h1>
    <p class="tagline">The one and only solution for any kind of mobila app landing needs. Just change the screenshots and texts and you are good to go. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder mt-3">
    <img src="images/iphonex.png" alt="phone" class="img-fluid">
    <video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
      <source src="https://static.lumosity.com/resources/home_page_templates/574/neuralnetwork.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
</header>
```